# Plotly express export to png inside for loop

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-express

I have a code where I am generating the pots using fig(show) inside a loop and this works fine. I would like to be able to export this into the different PNG files based on the for loop. I have tried different options like %s, but doesn't work;

```
my_dfs = {}
Name = ['A','B','C',]
for name in Name:

fig.write_image("C:\aa\pandas\VIP\%s.png" % name)
```

I would like to create A.png, B.png and C.png based on the loop.

Fig.show() shows me the images I need but I need to export to png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use raw string (prefixed with `r`)

```
r"C:\aa\pandas\VIP\%s.png"
```

In the normal string, python may replace sequence of backslash (\) and other characters with another character.